How does 7z implement AES encryption?
Questions:

Which AES algorithm mode is used in 7z? (Is it ECB, CBC, CFB, OFB, or CTR?)
When executing the command 7z a ArchiveName SomeDir -p, how does 7z perform encryption? Does it treat all data as a single solid file, or does it encrypt files individually, or maybe it creates blocks of a specific size for encryption?
If 7z uses data-blocks, how are these blocks created and what is their size?
How does 7z validate a password during decryption? Like, when it displays ERROR: Wrong password?, how does it deduce that the password is incorrect? Does it add certain headers before encryption or something?
Does 7z arrange files in alphabetical order for encryption/archiving when using the command 7z a ArchiveName SomeDir -p?

Motivation:
I managed to recover a deleted 7z archive (see this question for more details). The archive was password-protected and contained 17 sub-archives, all in 7z format. I managed to decrypt and extract 14 of them, but three of them remain inaccessible (one of these three "B.7z" is 90% decrypted/decompressed but lacks the final block, including file names and sizes). I guess the data-blocks (?) for these files may be corrupted. Here are some additional details about the archive:
7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,8 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz (806EA),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 125245022698 bytes (117 GiB)

Listing archive: Archive.7z

--
Path = Archive.7z
Type = 7z
Physical Size = 125245022698
Headers Size = 890
Method = LZMA2:24 7zAES
Solid = -
Blocks = 17

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2024-07-31 00:58:29 D....            0            0  DirName
2023-12-19 05:09:59 ....A    709350805    709388448  DirName/A.7z
2024-07-31 00:01:33 ....A   1586475200   1586559392  DirName/B.7z
2024-02-16 05:23:20 ....A   5813424658   5813733152  DirName/C.7z
2023-11-14 21:52:41 ....A  25460362975  25461713984  DirName/D.7z
2023-11-14 22:19:30 ....A   1713616561   1713707504  DirName/E.7z
2023-12-19 03:45:36 ....A  10539749018  10540308304  DirName/F.7z
2023-12-27 05:36:51 ....A   3637788779   3637981824  DirName/G.7z
2024-02-27 04:20:54 ....A   2566526729   2566662928  DirName/H.7z
2024-03-21 04:59:37 ....A   1180988362   1181051040  DirName/I.7z
2024-03-19 06:42:05 ....A   3751427829   3751626896  DirName/J.7z
2023-08-28 13:37:06 ....A  22618868536  22620068768  DirName/K.7z
2024-01-28 16:44:37 ....A   2768329573   2768476480  DirName/L.7z
2023-09-26 03:42:19 ....A  12245436464  12246086256  DirName/M.7z
2023-09-07 07:34:45 ....A   8162568245   8163001392  DirName/N.7z
2024-02-24 04:26:55 ....A   3300729037   3300904192  DirName/O.7z
2024-03-27 03:32:53 ....A   4387445171   4387677984  DirName/P.7z
2023-07-02 06:10:47 ....A  14795288170  14796073264  DirName/Q.7z
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2024-07-31 00:58:29       125238376112 125245021808  17 files, 1 folders

###########################
# ERRORS WHEN EXTRACTING:
###########################

ERROR: Data Error in encrypted file. Wrong password? : DirName/B.7z
ERROR: Data Error in encrypted file. Wrong password? : DirName/C.7z
ERROR: Data Error in encrypted file. Wrong password? : DirName/D.7z

Considering that each of these sub-7z files has a constant signature (Magic number + some flags: 37 7a bc af 27 1c 00 04), and knowing the password allows us to calculate its SHA-256 value for AES, is it possible to implement a reverse approach to recover the damaged parts?
Also, if I am certain that the corruption is within the first 8 GB of the file, can I decrypt/decompress some segments of DirName/D.7z?
I would greatly appreciate any guidance on recovering the damaged sections. I apologize for the lengthy and detailed question, and I would also appreciate any references for further reading.

https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/bugs/1467/ is an interesting read, if anything.  It might help.

@JayCravens , Thanks, it referred to WinZip(http://www.winzip.com/aes_info.htm), which specifically indicates that: "The file data is encrypted byte-for-byte using the AES encryption algorithm operating in "CTR" mode,", which is good news for me (probably bad news for those concerned about security) since a CTR mode cipher can be partially decrypted. However, the comments were from 2015, so there may have been changes to the code since then. We need more reliable information and references.
